# Spotlight search puts Finder window in background behind other windows

Tags: finder, spotlight, focus

Usually a Spotlight search presents choices, where clicking on one of the items found displays a Finder window with the item. I have probably been using this feature since I converted to Apple in 2009.

Starting with Monterey later versions, perhaps 12.4, when a Spotlight search displays a Finder window as described above, the Finder window is often not visible being behind other windows.

I was hoping that this problem would be fixed in Ventura. I upgraded yesterday to 13.4.1 but the problem still remains.

It seems that the problem is worse if there is a Terminal window open. I have seen some discussion of this issue that also refers to the issue being associated with the Terminal program, although usually in connections with Secure Keyboard Entry. That is not a factor in my case.

I have sent this as feedback to Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution:

1: "CMD + Space"
2: Search for what you are looking for:
3: "CMD + R" or "CMD + Enter"

Comment: This looks like a really simple solution. I will have to test it out for a bit. Suddenly today the search windows are all appearing in the foreground as expected, so have to have a situation where it fails to see if this fixes it.

Comment: I have now found several instances where clicking on an item in the Spotlight search results puts the window in the background, and when then doing a CMD-enter thereafter puts the window in the foreground. So I am adopting this as a standard procedure and marking this answer as correct. I am wondering if this is documented or discussed somewhere, as I have not seen it, but I have seen others asking the same question.